# Return to screen panels

Tags: 18.04, screen

So I learned more about how to use screens to the point where I came up with a nice 4 panel display, however, when I do Control A+D to detach the from the entire view back to the console and if I do, lets say, screen -r to back to the view, I go back to only one of the panels in which case if I terminate that one, I fall through the other 3.

Is there any way I can 'save' the setup and come back to it freely?

Comment: Please click [edit] to let us know these facts. 1) Which OS is installed (Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Kylin, Ubuntu Budgie, et al.)? 2) Which release number?  Please do not use Add Comment; Comments are a channel from us to you, whereas the Question should contain all the facts you have about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question on how to go to a specific screen? If yes labelling screens with screen -S screen_name and then you can go back to a particular screen with screen -r screen_name. If that's not the question could you provide more details